# Arquivo criado sem conteudo com PHP

Tags: php, windows-8

Tenho o `XAMPP` instalado em uma máquina com `Windows 8 Enterprise`.
Desenvolvendo em `PHP` acontece que ao carregar a página é criado um arquivo temporário na pasta `C:\Temp` tendo como conteúdo um determinado endereço IP.

```
$tmpfname = tempnam("C:\Temp","CCT_");
$handle = fopen($tmpfname, "w");
fwrite($handle, $circuito['loopback0']);
fclose($handle);
```

Ao renomear este arquivo temporário para um nome padrão.

```
$conn= rename($tmpfname, "C:\Temp\conecta.txt");
```

Ele é acessado posteriormente onde é lido este IP e utilizado para realizar uma conexão por `Telnet`.

Na minha maquina isso tudo funciona plenamente, porém ao acessar a página de outras máquinas, o arquivo chega a ser criado com o nome padrão, mas sem conteúdo (em branco).

O que pode esta gerando este problema?

Comment: Esse problema tem cara de permissões inválidas, pois os arquivos criados por meio da função `tempnam` possuem permissão `0600`, em que somente o criador pode ler e escrever no arquivo. Uma vez que o arquivo está sendo criado porém não há nada dele, a máquina não deve estar entendo o usuário da rede como "dono" do arquivo.

Comment: ha alguma forma de alterar a permissão ou outra forma de fazer com que este arquivo seja escrito pelos usuários que executarem?

Comment: Tente alterar a função `tempnam` pelas funções `sys_get_temp_dir` e `file_put_contents`, pois nesse caso os arquivos serão criados com as permissões para outros usuários escreverem neles. Ou simplesmente tente alterar as permissões com `chmod` antes de escrever.

Comment: Sem  sucesso tambem atraves do file_put_contents, e pelo chmod($tmpfname, 0755) antes da gração tambem nao funcionou.

Comment: Essa variável `$circuito['loopback0']` não funciona apenas para uma conexão local? O que você de fato está tentando gravar no arquivo?

Comment: neste arquivo é gravado um endereço ip, por exemplo: 10.76.0.50.
Este ip é o valor de $circuito['loopback0']. Na minha maquina ocorre tudo certo, o problema é quando acesso por outras maquinas (estão todas dentro da mesma rede/dominio)

Comment: Qual o conteúdo de `$circuito` quando você acessa o arquivo remotamente?

Comment: $circuito['loopback0'] é um campo do meu BD.
depois de criado o arquivo conecta.txt, ele é lido por um outro programa de acesso remoto, o  TeraTerm.